# Python virtualenv requirements.txt by default includes wheel

Tags: python, virtualenv, python-wheel

I just re-installed python & virtualenv after accidentally getting everything messy. I noticed that my requirements.txt in my newly created environment automatically includes wheel==0.24.0. Is this normal, and what is it? I understand that virtualenv should create new environments without any system-installed packages.

Answer (score 5):

I came across this issue when setting up virtualenv in windows.

To avoid wheel from being installed you can use the --no-wheel option.
virtualenv venv --no-wheel

To my understanding wheel is used handle a compressed format of a python package (.whl) that can be used by pip to speed up the install time. https://wheel.readthedocs.org/en/latest/

Answer (score -1):

Probably one of the itens listed in your requirements.txt needs wheel package installed to work.

Although it's a common (and good) pratice list the fundamental python packages of a project inside requirements.txt, not all of the packages the eventually will be installed are there.

Your pip log may helps you to point what package required wheel to be installed.